# Retrofit: Custom query parameter

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to call and enpoint like this one:

```
api/clients/{clientId}?filter=param1:null,param2:{param2}
```

There's one single param `filter`, but with a dynamic value `{param2}` inside it.

How can achieve this?

Comment: @Query should have helped you

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Query ? something like this

```
@GET("getAllOrders/US?limit=40&page=pagen")
Call<ReturnMainListOrder> getreturn_main(
        @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
        @Query("page") String page);
```

Comment: if I add `@Query("param2")` it will add `&param2=XXX` and I don't want to have that parameter, but `filter=param1:null,param2:XXX`